# Defining a branch of a function that is holomorphic on the unit disc.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I want to define a branch of $f(z) = (z^2+1)^\frac{1}{2}$ that is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \overline D_1(0)$.

Here I found a branch of $f$ that is holomorphic on $D_1(0)$ which I believe to be sufficient.

> Observe that $z^2 + 1 = (z+i)(z-i)$. We can define a branch of $f(z)$ holomorphic on $D_1(0)$ by finding a holomorphic function $g(z) \in \log((z-i)(z+i))$.
> $$\log((z-i)(z+i)) = \log(z-i) + \log(z+i)$$
> Any two branches of logarithms $\log_{\theta_1}$ and $\log_{\theta_2}$ will satisfy, for $z \neq \pm i$, $\log_{\theta_1}(z-i) + \log_{\theta_2}(z+i)$. We can choose $\theta_1 = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\theta_2 = \frac{\pi}{2}$ such that $g_1(z) = \log_{\theta_1}(z-i)$ and $g_2(z) = \log_{\theta_2}(z+i)$ are both holomorphic on $D_1(0)$, so $g(z) = g_1(z) + g_2(z)$ is also holomorphic on $D_1(0)$. Then, $f(z) = \exp(\frac{1}{2}g(z))$ is a holomorphic function on $D_1(0)$, as it has no branch points in this set. Then, $f(z) = \exp(\frac{1}{2}g(z))$ is a holomorphic function on $D_1(0).$

To find a branch of $f(z)$ that is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \overline D_1(0)$, I have been told to observe $f(z) = z^2(1+z^{-2})$. I am not sure what to do past defining $g_3(z) = \log_{\theta_3}(z^2), g_4(z) = \log_{\theta_4}(1+z^{-2})$.